# Detailed Page Views in Blogger API v3

Tags: java, android, google-api, blogger

I am currently working on an Android app with Blogger API v3. If I understood the documentation right, I can only retrieve page views for the last 7 days, last 30 days, and all time. Is there any way I can retrieve a more detailed version of page views, involving specific ranges? I would love it if I can include a graph in my app like the one on Blogger's website, but specific data is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Current Blogger API does not allow to retrieve other Page Views than for those set periods: 7 days, 30 days and all page views.

Maybe you could think of something with the use of Google Analytics